# cuando intento crear la tabla usuario me da ese error en ORACLE SQL

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

create table USUARIOS (
UsuarioId integer not null PRIMARY KEY,
Nombres varchar (30) not null,
Direccion varchar (150) not null,
);

Informe de error - ORA-00904: : identificador no válido
00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:

Comment: El *Action* no arrojo ningún mensaje?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No haría falta que indiques que UsuarioId es un campo not null, ya que al asignarlo como clave primaria, este automáticamente se crea con ese estado. La siguiente sentencia me ha funcionado correctamente:

```
create table USUARIOS ( 
    UsuarioId integer PRIMARY KEY, 
    Nombres varchar (30) not null, 
    Direccion varchar (150) not null
)
```

Comment: gracias. voy a corregir.